# How do I fix inconsistent Textarea bottom margin in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, textarea

I'm trying to eliminate the extra bottom margin that both FF and Chrome seem to give to Textareas. Surprisingly IE seems to do it correctly. I would like to avoid using conditional includes but CSS3 tweaks are OK.

**Sample Code**

```css
.red-box {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
textarea {
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    margin: 0px; /* Has no effect */
}
```

```html
<div class="red-box">
    <textarea>No Margin Please!</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW, I can no longer reproduce this issue on Firefox 45. It still appears on Chromium 48, though.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

By default, I believe both Chrome and Firefox will set these elements as `display: inline-block;`.  Set `display: block` in your styles and you should be all set.

Comment: Great. But then you also have to explicitly set `margin` with `!important`. Because Chrome seems to keep the margins of the textarea to its container "fixed" when textarea uses `display: block`... (You may take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60204423 that addresses that issue.)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to leave it inline, simply try

```
vertical-align: top
```

Comment: Never knew about this! Good if you don't want to make it a block :)

Answer (score 11):

Set `display: block` for your textarea.

Answer (score 3):

Just bit by this in 2022 Chrome!

`<textarea>` has a default of `vertical-align: baseline`, which visually manifests as excess bottom margin.

Interestingly, none of the most popular reset/normalize stylesheets change this property. In my personal reset, I have added:

```css
vertical-align: bottom
```

Answer (score -4):

Just disable resize as follow

textarea{resize: none;}