# Textarea Height 100%, without increasing height of parent table row?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the textarea height to 100%, without increasing the height of the parent table row.

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCPRX/14).

You can see that the row with only inputs is the right height, the row with just text are the right height, but the rows with the textarea is too tall.

I told the textarea to be 100% of the parent's height. I expected the textarea to get the rows height, and set itself to that. Instead, it's sets its own height to whatever it wants, then the row gets set to the textarea's height, so that it is 100%, just not the "right" 100%!

I can set a `max-height` on the textarea, and that works, but it blocks the user from making the textarea any taller.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here that are keeping you from achieving what you want.

**1)**

You have `min-height: 26px;` set for the `textarea` which is greater than the height set for the table cell. Remove this from your CSS.

**2)**

You have 5px of padding on the top and bottom of the `textarea`, essentially adding 10px of space. Change those to 0px and you'll notice a change.

**3)**

The height of a `textarea` is also determined by its number of [rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). Add `rows="1"` to the text area and it should fall into place.

**4)**

I forgot this earlier, also add `valign="top"` to the `<td>` containing the `textarea` that will keep it inside the cell instead of having that 1-2px overage... I've updated the fiddle showing this.

Edit: Since it was pointed out that `valign` is deprecated, you can also use `vertical-align: text-top;` on the `td` containing the `textarea`

Here is a fiddle with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/38GAX/1/

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't change the fact - the textarea is still higher, have a look at your own fiddle :)

Comment: I added the `min-height: 26px;` during testing,I forgot to remove it when I created the fiddle. With `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` the height 100% should be inclusive of any padding set. I added `rows="1"` and it made the text area shorter, but it is still ignoring the css height.

Comment: @DrydenLong `valign="top"` is deprecated!

Comment: @webeno in which case, you can use `vertical-align: text-top;` instead

Comment: It still isn't the same height- it's still making the textarea taller?

Comment: @Nick Looking at my fiddle, the textarea is the same height as the rest of the row... What browser are you using?

Comment: I see, I'm using Chrome and it looks fine, but on FF it does look larger. You might have to inspect the elements and see if there are any vendor specific CSS rules that you need to over-write.

Comment: FF really sucks, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
textarea {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid #55CCEE;
    color: #646464;
    height:100%;
    min-height:26px;
    width:100%;
    min-width:180px;
    padding:5px 11px 5px 10px;
    display:block // <-- this is the line I added

}
```

Looks like Chrome and Firefox will set textarea to `display:inline-block;`. Use `display:block` instead.

Source: [How do I fix inconsistent Textarea bottom margin in Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453959/how-do-i-fix-inconsistent-textarea-bottom-margin-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: I added that to the fiddle (and to my real files) but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: which fiddle did you add it to? I just added it to yours and it works for me: [http://jsfiddle.net/mCPRX/17/](http://jsfiddle.net/mCPRX/17/)

Comment: think I found it: apply both, `display:block` (on the CSS) AND `rows="1"` (this one on the textarea tag itself - as suggested by @DrydenLong) and it should work, tested it on Firefox: [http://jsfiddle.net/mCPRX/18/](http://jsfiddle.net/mCPRX/18/)

Comment: @webeno the textarea is not larger, just the text inputs' height can't be set successfully in FireFox (although that's possible when the text input is placed outside the table cell), FireFox really sucks, so you don't need to support it with highest expectation, just accept a little break in layout and there are only a small amount of users (who use FireFox) will have to experience that acceptable layout bug.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is apply a negative `margin`.

So add

```
textarea {
    ...
    margin-bottom:-4px;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mCPRX/15/