# Textarea width issue in div

Tags: html, css, textarea

I just want to put a `textarea` into a `div`, I think it should not be a problem:

**CODE**

```css
.panel {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.panel textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

This is a very difficult code, isn't it?  All of us did it thousand of times.

For some reason, this width of the `textarea` is buggy at right side. Checking the box model of `.panel` seems good.

Tried it in FF, Chrome, Edge, same result everywhere.

Can somebody explain me, why is it, and what is the solution for it?

I've made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/betq6eo3/) just for fun.

Comment: What is the problem ? Is it because when you expand your text area it overlaps the container ? If yes just add `overflow:hidden;` to panel.

Comment: I do not want nothing. I just want to fix the right side of the textarea. As you see, at right side there isn't the `10px` padding of div.

Comment: add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your text area.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi that worked. But why is it? Other elements just works as I expected. Add as an answer if you want, to allow me to accept.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the `<textarea>` a `box-sizing: border-box` should fix it.:

```
.panel {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

.panel textarea {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/betq6eo3/4/)

I also added a `display:block` to the textarea to eliminate some inconsistency in bottom margins on textareas ([How do I fix inconsistent Textarea bottom margin in Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453959/how-do-i-fix-inconsistent-textarea-bottom-margin-in-firefox-and-chrome))

Comment: `display:block` isn't doing anything there

Comment: I'm setting it to `display: block;` to eliminate extra spacing that Firefox and Chrome add to the bottom of textareas - though you are correct that it's inrelated to the right padding issue. I'll update my answer. Reference for textarea padding inconsistency: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453959/how-do-i-fix-inconsistent-textarea-bottom-margin-in-firefox-and-chrome

Answer (score 3):

you should apply [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) universally instead of just `div`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.panel textarea,
.panel input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, nice - as a rule of thumb I generally do a blanket `box-sizing: border-box` rule for all elements at the start of my CSS files. Only rarely do I revert to browser defaults for the `box-sizing` property on certain elements.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs because by default textareas have padding and a border. When you set width to 100%, the textarea is actually becoming 100% + padding-left/right + border-left/right-width. Setting the textarea to box-sizing: border-box will make the padding/border fit inside the specified width rather than outside of it.

```
.panel textarea {width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Here's a visual example:
https://css-tricks.com/examples/BoxSizing/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that try adding padding of 0 to your textarea, as box-sizing:border-box result differs on some browsers.

```
.panel textarea{
 width: 100%;
 padding:0;
}
```