# How to make textarea element cover the entire width and height of its parent container?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have this HTML code:

```
<div style="border: 2px red solid; background: blue;">
    <textarea rows="6" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></textarea>
</div>
```

We can see the blue background of the parent container element around the edges of the textarea.  Is there a way to full stretch the textarea to cover the entire parent it is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You don't need to set `height: 100%`, since the `rows` attribute of your `<textarea>` element is setting the height (and the height of the parent `<div>`).
2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453959/how-do-i-fix-inconsistent-textarea-bottom-margin-in-firefox-and-chrome#answer-3454002) for a similar problem. The `<textarea>` element is rendered with `display: inline-block;` by default, so setting `display: block;` should the trick.

```html
<div style="border: 2px red solid; background: blue;">
    <textarea rows="6" style="width: 100%; display: block;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```